# Can Scrum and Project Management live together?

Tags: agile, scrum, methodology

Can Scrum and Project Management live together?

Can you take the best of both worlds or will combining these two methods?

Comment: Scrum *is* a project management methodology - do you mean 'can scrum and waterfall planning live side by side'?

Comment: People are always trying to incorporate different ideas. For example, Scrumban: http://www.lulu.com/content/3864767

Comment: Don't understand the question. Scrum is a project management methodology, isn't it? ... if scrum could live with itself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 7):

A few things to consider:

- Scrum is about empowering the team as opposed to command and control management style.
- There is no manager in Scrum, there is a ScrumMaster which is a servant leader.
- The ScrumMaster is responsible for the Scrum process, making sure it is used correctly and maximizes its benefits.
- The ScrumMaster has to remove impediments so that the team can do his job in a productive way.
- Scrum implements transparency with a minimal set of practices/roles/ceremonies and there is no real paperwork.
- There is no real PMO type work in Scrum, most of PMO work is (considered as) waste.

So please, keep your PM habits away :)

And during an adoption, I'd recommend to do it as in the book (Shu), don't try to adapt it for now (Ri) (see Alistair Cockburn on [Shu Ha Ri](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Shu+Ha+Ri)). I wouldn't even consider things like Scrumban (a modified version of Scrum using Kaban for continuous flow, no more iterations) at the start.

PS: Agile methods have all been influenced by the Lean movement (most, if not all, Agile manifesto signatories had *The Machine That Changed The World* in their shelves). Some could say Agile methods are a transposition of lean concepts (for new product development) to software development; others would say Agile and Lean share the same theory (see for example Jeff Sutherland's article [The First Scrum: Was it Scrum or Lean?](http://jeffsutherland.com/scrum/2007/11/is-it-scrum-or-lean.html)). To me, there are obvious similarities (it would be easy to map the whole [Toyota Production System "House"](http://www.swmas.co.uk/info/index.php/Toyota-Production-System) on Agile practices) and I find Lean useful to understand how Agile works and how to implement an Agile process efficiently. So I use Lean as an as an additional toolbox. But to me, Scrum has already everything to make your development process lean, if well implemented. So there is no need to mix it. Just apply it (Shu).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Scrum and the PMO can live together. They're concerned with different things though, so the edges where the two meet are going to have to give a little. There will be some conflict at the intersection. Traditional PMBOK approaches are a poor fit to product development domains like software development, but there's quite a bit of smart statistical controls in the PMBOK, and skilled project managers who can be taught to manage flow rather than schedule are precious.

Neither Scrum nor Lean nor the Toyota organization suggest that either hierarchy or directed authority are off-limits. The definition of "Self-Organization" has been significantly stretched by software developers over the years until it has become largely indistinguishable from "Self-Determination", which was never the intention.

Toyota, for example, is a very hierarchical organization that depends very much on command and control. The difference is that it's a Learning Organization and managers at Toyota are required to have mastery of the work done in their purview, and have a duty to teach that work to workers. Team members at Toyota who envision possible improvements to their work and to the process are coached by their managers through the scientific process to prove their ideas. It helps that the process isn't shaped to fit the organization, but that the organization shifts to fit a process that is continually improved.

There is always an element of command and control in any organization. Even Scrum teams are subject to it. Even if a work team itself is perfectly flat, a Product Owner can still call the ball. Software teams have seniors and juniors, and their opinions are not perfectly equal. On Lean teams, managers are expected to be masters of the work, or have, as Toyota calls it, "towering technical competence". If management isn't skilled or is too far from the work, then they'll likely make bad decisions about the work. This is the real problem, and Self-Directed Work Teams (SDWT) are a predictable result of workers seeking to insulate themselves from poor management. SDWT is not the best answer, but it might be the limit of what an organization might achieve.

And finally, Scrum is not a project management methodology - at least not from the perspective of the rigor of the PMBOK or of Lean. But then, the application of the PMBOK to software development without significant modification to account for the nature of product development is often a fool's errand, so efforts to displace the PMBOK on software teams is understandable.

At best, Scrum is a timebox planning methodology. That's still valuable if it's the thing you need, but there's nothing inherent in software work management that suggests you need timeboxes like sprints and iterations. In fact, the upwelling of interest in iteration-less approaches like Kanban and Flow-Based management are a testament to this.

In the end, there a heck of a lot of orthodoxy built up around Scrum now that wasn't introduced by Scrum's founders and leaders, and often isn't supported by them. The same can be said about how PMOs operate. Focus on the principles of flow and learning cultures and you might be able to avoid the blind alleys and myths that gather around methodologies once they've been in the mainstream for five years or so.

Answer (score 5):

***Has anyone tried to incorporate different ideas (scrum, six sigma, pmp, lean?)***

Essentially all of the above derive from the Japanese Quality Movement in the early 1980's.
It's all about increasing quality by reducing [waste, called Muda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muda_(Japanese_term)) in Japan

Lean was Toyota's implementation of the Quality Philosophies
and Six Sigma was General Electric's attempt to Americanize Lean based on corporate culture of the day.

Fast forward 20 years and the IT industry have realized that all this 'lean' thinking is a great idea for building better quality software, faster.  In what has been labelled [Agile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_Manifesto).

XP (extreme programming) and SCRUM are just two different implementations of Agile techniques.

Traditional management and software management is coming up against these new ways of thinking.

You can't have it all. Either your focus is on command and hierarchy (DO AS YOUR TOLD, traditional approach) vs Collaboration and working together to reduce wastes and deliver amazing things to customers (LETS DO IT TOGETHER, new model).

If you want to go deeper on this, the best approach is to read back on the original LEAN philosophies and then see how you think they can best be applied to project management. Many of best project management ideas were already considered as part of the original Lean movement, read the book 'The Toyota Way' and look into Lean that is where you can find your own answers.

Google: the seven types of muda for a start.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make sense since scrum is a project management framework but here are some things to consider:

1. Quality is the sole responsibility of the Team; not any PM.
2. Not sure what you mean by "artifacts", but the few scrum has (backlog, burndown) are maintained by the PO and Team under the guidance of the ScrumMaster.
3. There were no "best parts" to waterfall to want to consider continuing to use once you embrace Agile.
4. There is no "paperwork" in scrum; its considered waste.
5. People try to combine things all the time.  But most of the time they get the WORST of all worlds; not the best.  Most mistakes teams make in implementing scrum is to make excuses for why they can't do it the right way.  Then they claim it would be better to combine in something else and just make a mess of the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going it from the wrong side.

First you need to know what kind of team you have. Then start from that knowledge and use the appropriate methodology for your team. Rather than trying to use some methodology for your team. Do a methodology for your team. That means see what they are comfortable doing and what they think would benefit all of them.

For example: Usually when a team failed using RUP, it wasn't because they didn't follow the guidelines, but because they tried to follow all of them.

Generally I think it's better if developers don't have to do paperwork and logistics. Either they are bad at it or they would be more productive doing development.

Answer (score 0):

Found this useful link today, regarding **The software industry has an appaling record for project delivery**. Which address your exact question.

Suggest you browse around this site to get more of an idea:

http://behaviour-driven.org/SoftwareIndustryRecordOfFailure

The above the wiki for the very excellent [Dan North](http://dannorth.net) who proposed the idea of Behaviour Driven Design (Premise: The way we think depends on the language we use and this can be applied to software also).

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, Scrum *is* a project management process, so asking if Scrum and project management can coexist is like asking if water and H2O can coexist.

Second, the PMBOK defines the project manager role as having responsibility for the success of a project. Similarly, in Scrum the Product Owner is responsible for ROI, so the responsibilities of these roles are similar even if their duties are different. Scrum eschews a command-and-control management structure, emphasizing the need for self-managed and self-empowered teams that collectively make commitments and own delivering on those commitments under the principle that the people who do the work make and own the commitment... no responsibility without authority. In Scrum, the Product Owner provides guidance to the team via the product backlog prioritization and by the defined acceptance criteria for each backlog item ("Here's what I need done and here's the functionality that must exist for me to be happy"). The Product Owner also has the final say as to whether something is done or not; if the team doesn't complete a backlog item to the Product Owner's satisfaction *for any reason* then the Product Owner can reject the work. I'd say that makes the Product Owner a very powerful and important role in Scrum... IMO the most important role in terms of project success.

You might want to read [this blogpost on selecting the Product Owner](http://forums.construx.com/blogs/johnclif/archive/2009/08/13/transitioning-to-scrum-selecting-the-product-owner.aspx) for more information on the Product Owner role.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way I read your post is that the PM does 2 things:

1) Creates artifacts necessary for the business (like compliance)

2) Manage the project

As far as #2 goes, that job becomes encompassed in the PO and SM roles. The PM continuing to do it will add confusion and hurt the process.

As for #1, that is a vital role. If the business needs this, why not add the creation of these artifacts as part of the definition of "done" and add them to the team as a member who performs this specialized task. Alternatively, you could do this outside Scrum with no one even aware that it's happening, then perhaps providing those artifacts to the PO.

Answer (score 0):

Scrum is project management, just not the way project managers do it, but as Scrum does it. In short, Scrum does the compelte opposite of what people think of and are tought about project management. So, from that angle, I would say no.

On the other hand, project managers can be very efficient Product Owners.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is an absolute YES. 
Great question by the way.

More detailed information on this can be found here: http://www.blog.pmmetrics.com/#!SCRUM-Traditional-Project-Management-Chaos-in-IT-Industry/uiho7/577428320cf2e26a9986aa33